# Velcro external SSD to back of screen of MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I have seen some people velcro an external SSD to the back of the screen of their MacBook. Is there any risk to the MacBook itself, other than minor cosmetic problems? Specifically, I was wondering, if an SSD is running at it's maximum temperature, could this damage the screen for example?

[image]

Comment: I suppose it would take a lot of heat for the display to suffer any damage. Plus the velcro inbetween would make it additionally hard for the heat to transfer to the display. Some danger that would spring to mind is if the MacBook is closed and weight is put on it you have this central spot, where the SSD is, where it would take the entire weight, potentially increasing the risk of cracking the display/glas.

Comment: If someone sits on the computer, I don’t think it makes any real difference.